# How to count attributes (columns) from a txt file in Python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file that has rows and columns of data in it. I am trying to figure out how to count the number of columns (attributes) in the whole txt file. Here is my code to read the txt file and to count the columns but it is giving me the wrong answer.

```
    import pandas as pd 

    data_file = pd.read_csv('3human_evolution.txt')
    data_file.columns = data_file.columns.str.strip()
    A=len(data_file.columns)
    print(A)
```

Comment: this line `data_file.columns = data_file.columns.str.strip()` - doesn't make much sense to me. If you have `sep=','` (default), then why would you want to split columns by spaces/tabs? Can you provide a few first lines of your file?

Comment: not seeing how could possibly pandas give you the wrong count here? and `strip()` will only take out spaces from left and right most given there are any. on command line if you do `df.columns` it gives a list[str]. you should do no more than `len(df.columns)` to get the count here. what's the wrong answer you getting? what did you expect ?

Comment: if you can read the file using `read_csv` then you can get the number of rows and columns like this: `print data_file.shape`

Comment: It is printing that there is one column but really there are five. I am still not getting the correct answer even with what y'all are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

`len` gives you *all* elements in the DataFrame (product of rows and columns). The number of rows and columns are accessible with `DataFrame.shape`. `shape` gives you a tuple where the first entry is the number of rows and the second the number of columns. So you can print the number of columns with:

```
print(data_file.shape[1])
```